# How can I set default values for an object's keys?

Tags: javascript, web, idioms

A function receives an object `o`. The function requires it has four keys, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. For each one that is `undefined`, we want to set a custom default value. One option would be:

```
function func(o) {
    o.a = o.a || 12;
    o.b = o.b || function() {}
    // and so on
}
```

But is there a more elegant or idiomatic option?

Comment: @RickHitchcock Of course you're right, fixed that.

Comment: What if `o.a` is `0`, and you actually meant for that to be the value?

Answer (score 3):

Note your approach will overwrite falsy values different than `undefined`, like `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `false`.

Assuming you only want the enumerable own properties of `o`, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
function func(o) {
  o = Object.assign({
    a: 12,
    b: function() {}
  }, o);
}
```

Basically, it creates a new object with the default values, and overwrites it with the data from the argument.

Comment: @AvivCohn It's part of ES6. Supported by Chrome 45, Firefox 34, Edge build 10240, Opera 32, Safari 9. [It can be polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).